# does = when declaring a variable the same as copy constructor c++?

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor

I made class time ,
and declared in main :

```
time a;
time b=a;
```

is this the same as :

```
time b(a);
```

???
 I also made function :

```
time f(time t)
{
  return t;
}
```

and used it in main after declaring a :

```
time b=f(a);
```

I printed messages when copy constructor called , the Result was only 2 calls to copy constructor ,one copying a to t, the other is copying t to return , here is my question there was no call to copy constructor to copy the value returned from function to b ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: it is easy to see if you add some tracing cout << in your default ctor, copy ctor and assignment operator.

Comment: @AndersK I did that and thats why I asked the last question the answers seems return optmization !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question in your header and the question at the bottom of your post are different.  For the one in your header:

> does = when declaring a variable the same as copy constructor c++?

Not exactly.  First the expression on the right side is converted to the type on the left side, and then the copy constructor is called.  This requires an implicit conversion.  If one is not possible, the initialization will not compile.  If the expression on the right side is already the right type, then the first step is not necessary.

For your other question, this is [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `time b = a` is equivalent to `time b( a )` because you are declaring the object and assigning its value at the same time.

For the second part of your question, the compiler will in general remove unnecessary object copies where it can, depending on the optimization level.

Answer (score 0):

when an object is being created from another object, the copy constructor is called like

time b = a;
   or time b(a);

but when the object is already created and you want to copy items to it, then the operator= 
is called

the difference is like when you are using dynamically allocated memory
if you use copy constructor, that means that you are not already created, therefore you don't need any cleanup of your memory management

but when you assign an object to another, first it has to deal with the dynamically allocated elements of its own, like free memory, then copy them to its own

Answer (score -1):

no, b=a uses the assignment operator (operator=) to create a new, blank time object and then call the operator to move the values into it (or whatever else you tell operator= to do).

Often you'll find the compiler-generated versions of this will call the copy constructor, but it doesn't have to.

For reference, look up the [explicit](http://www.glenmccl.com/tip_023.htm) keyword. As copying an object can be done in 2 ways (copy ctor, and assignment operator), this tells the compiler to only use the copy ctor when explicitly invoked, not implicitly.

Create your class with all the different constructors (including the new c++0x move one) and the assignment operator and look what happens when you run it through the debugger.

Comment: This is wrong.  When used for initialization, `=` is not `operator=`.

Comment: Since we got C++11 now: If an `operator=` would be called it wouldn't move `a`, but copy it into `b`. Important difference.